# How to print <td> table before conditional switch php in the loop

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I have table and table have loop for call values of my field...

problem is everytime I set conditional on the `<td>` with `php switch` and everytime value is empty `<td>` is hide and my table is deform and disassemble
how can I print `<td></td>` anyway and print value just everytime values is not empty?

```
   <tr>
 <?php foreach($rows as $array_value) {


    switch ($array_value['value']) {

        case "1": print '<td>one</td>'; break;  
        case "2": print '<td>two</td>'; break;
        case "3": print '<td>three</td>'; break;
        case "4": print '<td>four</td>'; break;
        case "5": print '<td>five</td>'; break;
        case "6": print '<td>six</td>'; break;

    }

} ?>

</tr>
```

**UPDATED** :

Problem is 
Everytime value is empty, wrong value entered in cell !

[image: Picture]

Comment: You could use the [default case](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `default` to your switch statement to catch any other case than the defined ones:

```
switch ($array_value['value']) {

    case "1": print '<td>one</td>'; break;  
    case "2": print '<td>two</td>'; break;
    case "3": print '<td>three</td>'; break;
    case "4": print '<td>four</td>'; break;
    case "5": print '<td>five</td>'; break;
    case "6": print '<td>six</td>'; break;
    default: print '<td>empty</td>'; break;

}
```

That way round you are covered for an empty value(as well as any other).

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'default' case :

```
 <?php foreach($rows as $array_value) {

     switch ($array_value['value']) {

        case "1": print '<td>one</td>'; break;  
        case "2": print '<td>two</td>'; break;
        case "3": print '<td>three</td>'; break;
        case "4": print '<td>four</td>'; break;
        case "5": print '<td>five</td>'; break;
        case "6": print '<td>six</td>'; break;
        default: print '<td></td>';// Add this line

    }


} ?>

</tr>
```

When you omit the `default` value and `switch` gets a value that does not match any case, then there is no `td` inside the `tr` and the table is deformed. `default` works when no case statement is true.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? can i use IF ?

Comment: @BijanZand, where do you want to use the `if` ? Think about the `switch` statement well first. You have a `break` after every `case` statement. That means if any case statement is true, next `case` statements will not execute because of that `break`. But if you have a `default` as well, then if no `case`  statement is true, `default` will execute.

Comment: My problem is some empty <td>,s replace wrong value and Empty tags not render currectly !

Comment: What you say is not clear. if no `case` statement is true, then what do you want to show inside the `tr`?

Comment: i want if value is empty <TD>none</TD> is print on the cell

Comment: Then you need,  `default: print '<td>none</td>';` - is that what you want ?

Comment: Can you please see my picture in Update section ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165748/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-bijan-zand).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

```
 <?php foreach($rows as $array_value) {


    switch ($array_value['value']) {

        case "1": print '<td>one</td>'; break;  
        case "2": print '<td>two</td>'; break;
        case "3": print '<td>three</td>'; break;
        case "4": print '<td>four</td>'; break;
        case "5": print '<td>five</td>'; break;
        case "6": print '<td>six</td>'; break;
        default: print '<td></td>'; break;
    }

} ?>
```